# how to create a dynamic menu in Jekyll that auto-populates nav items when creating new pages

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am wondering how to go about creating a dynamic menu in Jekyll that automatically populates the navigation with nav items whenever a new page is created. I read an [article](https://thinkshout.com/blog/2014/12/creating-dynamic-menus-in-jekyll/) that touched a bit on the subject, but it was geared toward just sub-nav items. Has anyone had any experience in doing something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to do this automatically. However, it is very easy to achieve. Here is the code:

```
<ul>
  {% for item in site.pages %}
    <li {% if page.url contains item.url %}class="active"{% endif %}>
      <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Source: https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/simple-menu/

To define the order of appearence, you might want to add a front matter variable called 'order' to the pages and add a different pagenumber to this variable on each page. The code should sort the pages before looping over them. That looks like this:

```
{% assign sitepages = site.pages | sort: order %}
{% for item in site.pages %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to do this automatically?

Comment: 'Why is it a bad idea to do this automatically?', you asked. Well... it slows down the build and it requires complex code. Code complexity = cost.